# store images with MediaStore to specific folder

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-mediascanner

I was searching a bit on how to add images using the mediastore since I'm currently doing it manual with

```
final String myBitmap = "MyImage_"+ mFileDate + ".png";
File fileNumber = new File(APP_FILE_PATH, myBitmap);
out = new FileOutputStream( fileNumber );
final Bitmap mBitmap =getBitmap();
mBitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, out );
out.flush();
```

however I need the IDs that media manager uses to store since its easier to manage id rather than paths and such.
I tried adding it this way:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, mFileName.getName());
values.put(Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, getString(R.string.bitdraw_description));
values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/png");

Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
out = getContentResolver().openOutputStream(uri);
mBitmap.compress( Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, out );
out.flush();
```

however this adds the image to the folder where the photos are saved and not to the specific folder I want to.

Also tried this after the manual (first part):

```
Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), mFileName.getPath(), mFileName.getName(), getString(R.string.description));
```

but this only generates duplicates since the image was saved first by the `outputStream`

A workaround I found on a thread here is to call a broadcast like this:

`sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse    ("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));`

but this is rather inneficient and takes long, and I want it to be the fastest, and I'm quite unsure if this actually generates the IDs, and if it does, how could I make this to scan only a specific folder in the SD ??
Any help would be appreciated.